# Reading executing assembly signature pfx / cert

Tags: c#, code-signing, digital-signature, digital-certificate

This is an academic question trying to understand new material. Not academic in the sense of formal school but in the sense of ongoing education and wanting to get a handle on an area of development I have not been exposed to before.

So in my understanding I create an assembly and by "signing it" I have created a strong name / X509Certificate.

So I create an empty winapp. I go to the project properties on the signing tab and sign the assembly using a password.

A file testing.pfx is added to my project.

In the form load I then execute this code thinking I would see my assembly signing cert only I don't as it is null...??

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Module mod = ass.GetModules().First();
X509Certificate cert = mod.GetSignerCertificate();
```

cert is null. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong to retrieve the cert or do I have things jumbled up in my head and what I am looking for isn't where I am looking?

Thank You

---

Edit

@p e p I have used the following after reading your post and msdn.

> signtool sign /a C:/....../MyFile.exe
>
> signtool sign /f C:/....../MyCert.pfx /p MyPassword C:/....../MyFile.exe

Both said they completed with success. However running the code block above still produces a null cert.

Now what I may have missed or am doing wrong is I am working with visual studio debug version and that is the path to the exe that I used for signing.

c:....\LicensedControlTest\obj\x86\Debug

Comment: There are two different kinds of signing which often get confused. Strong-name signing and code signing (i.e. a digital signature such as Authenticode). See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/03/what-s-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming.aspx). A certificate is only present for the latter kind of signing. You having simply applied a strong name to the assembly.

Comment: @mikez Thank You. The article from Eric helped explain the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Authenticode sign  the assembly. You can do this by using the File Signing Tool (Signcode.exe) which will sign your assembly with an Authenticode signature. Essentially you just run a command using `signcode` which will Authenticode sign your assembly.

If you look at the doc for `GetSignerCertificate`, you will see that `null` is expected if the assembly is not authenticode signed.

```
signcode /spc myCertificate.spc /v myKey.pvk  myAssembly
```

That's the basics, you can find more info here on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9sh96ycy(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: See edit. I'm sure you are 100% correct and I am just doing something wrong.